# Significance of learning 32 bit exploitation

Tags: windows, 32bit-64bit, exploit, instructions, microprocessors

I'm thinking of taking *EXP 301 (Windows User Mode Exploit Development)* exam. And I did some research on this exam; I came around many articles which criticised the exam material for only covering 32 bit (x86 Windows Exploits). So I want to know what is the significance of learning 32 bit exploitation.
Is this a pre-requisite to learn 64 bit exploitation?
Wouldn't it be better to learn about exploits on 64 bit system considering almost every system is 64 bit nowadays?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a pre-requisite to learn 64 bit exploitation?

No.  There is a lot in common between x86-32 and x86-64, so much of what you learned about 32 bits would carry over, but it's not a prerequisite.

> Wouldn't it be better to learn about exploits on 64 bit system considering almost every system is 64 bit nowadays?

In general I would say yes (though there are a lot of legacy systems in the world).  That's why people are criticizing the exam.